# Visit Half Million Pages with Perl

Tags: perl, web-crawler, www-mechanize, lwp

Currently I'm using Mechanize and the get() method to get each site, and check with content() method each mainpage for something.
I have a very fast computer + 10Mbit connection, and still, it took 9 hours to check 11K sites, which is not acceptable, the problem is, the speed of the get() function, which , obviously, needs to get the page,is there any way to make it faster,maybe to disable something,as I only need to main page html to be checked.

Thanks,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make queries in parallel instead of serially. If I needed to do this, I'd fork off a process to grab the page. Something like [Parallel::ForkManager](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Parallel::ForkManager), [LWP::Parallel::UserAgent](http://www.metacpan.org/module/LWP::Parallel::ParallelUserAgent) or [WWW:Curl](http://www.metacpan.org/module/WWW::Curl) may help. I tend to favor [Mojo::UserAgent](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Mojo::UserAgent).

Comment: Perfect!!!! Thanks a lot!. I didnt know you can multithread with Perl, never actually looked for this type of feature when using perl, it really comes handy in this case.

Comment: Well, My mistake. I meant processes.

Answer (score 7):

Use `WWW::Curl` (and specifically [WWW::Curl::Multi](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW::Curl)). I'm using it to crawl 100M+ pages per day. The module is a thin binding on top of `libcurl`, so it feels a bit C-ish, but it's fast and does almost anything libcurl is capable of doing.

I would not recommend using LWP::Parallel::UA, as it's kind of slow and the module itself is not very well thought out. When I started out writing a crawler, I originally thought about forking LWP::Parallel::UA, but I decided against that when I looked into it's internals.

Disclaimer: I'm the current maintainer of the `WWW::Curl` module.