# How can I make my Perl web crawler go faster?

Tags: perl, performance, web-crawler

I've been knocking up a little pet project the last two days which consists of making a crawler in Perl.

I have no real experience in Perl (only what I have learned in the past two days).
My script is as follows:

ACTC.pm:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use URI;
use URI::http;
use File::Basename;
use DBI;
use HTML::Parser;
use LWP::Simple;
require LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->timeout(10);
$ua->env_proxy;
$ua->max_redirect(0);


package Crawler;
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {
        _url => shift,
        _max_link => 0,
        _local => 1,
    };
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;

}
sub trim{
    my( $self, $string ) = @_;
    $string =~ s/^\s+//;
    $string =~ s/\s+$//;
    return $string;
}
sub process_image {
    my ($self, $process_image) = @_;
    $self->{_process_image} = $process_image;
}
sub local {
    my ($self, $local) = @_;
    $self->{_local} = $local;
}
sub max_link {
    my ($self, $max_link) = @_;
    $self->{_max_link} = $max_link;
}
sub x_more {
    my ($self, $x_more) = @_;
    $self->{_x_more} = $x_more;
}
sub resolve_href {
    my ( $self, $base, $href) = @_;
    my $u = URI->new_abs($href, $base);
    return $u->canonical;   
}
sub write {
    my ( $self, $ref, $data ) = @_;
    open FILE, '>c:/perlscripts/' . $ref . '_' . $self->{_process_image} . '.txt';
    foreach( $data ) {
        print FILE $self->trim($_) . "\n";
    }
    close( FILE );
}
sub scrape {
    my ( @m_error_array, @m_href_array, @href_array, $dbh, $query, $result, $array );
    my ( $self, $DBhost, $DBuser, $DBpass, $DBname ) = @_;
    if( defined( $self->{_process_image} ) && ( -e 'c:/perlscripts/href_w_' . $self->{_process_image} . ".txt" ) ) {
        open  ERROR_W, "<c:/perlscripts/error_w_" . $self->{_process_image} . ".txt";
        open  M_HREF_W, "<c:/perlscripts/m_href_w_" . $self->{_process_image} . ".txt";
        open  HREF_W, "<c:/perlscripts/href_w_" . $self->{_process_image} . ".txt";
        @m_error_array = <ERROR_W>;
        @m_href_array = <M_HREF_W>;
        @href_array = <HREF_W>;
        close ( ERROR_W );
        close ( M_HREF_W );
        close ( HREF_W );
    }else{
        @href_array = ( $self->{_url} );
    }
    my $z = 0;
    while( @href_array ){
        if( defined( $self->{_x_more} ) && $z == $self->{_x_more} ) {
            print "died";
            last;
        }
        my $href = shift( @href_array );
        if( defined( $self->{_process_image} ) && scalar @href_array ne 0 ) {
            $self->write( 'm_href_w', @m_href_array );
            $self->write( 'href_w', @href_array );
            $self->write( 'error_w', @m_error_array );
        }
        $self->{_link_count} = scalar @m_href_array;
        my $info = URI::http->new($href);
        if( ! defined( $info->host ) ) {
            push( @m_error_array, $href );
        }else{
            my $host = $info->host;
            $host =~ s/^www\.//;
            $self->{_current_page} = $href;
            my $redirect_limit = 10;
            my $y = 0;
            my( $response, $responseCode );
            while( 1 && $y le $redirect_limit ) {
                $response = $ua->get($href);
                $responseCode = $response->code;
                if( $responseCode == 200 || $responseCode == 301 || $responseCode == 302 ) {
                    if( $responseCode == 301 || $responseCode == 302 ) {
                        $href = $self->resolve_href( $href, $response->header('Location') );
                    }else{
                        last;
                    }
                }else{
                    last;
                }
                $y++;
            }
            if( $y != $redirect_limit && $responseCode == 200 ) {
                print $href . "\n";
                if( ! defined( $self->{_url_list} ) ) {
                    my @url_list = ( $href );
                }else{
                    my @url_list = $self->{_url_list};
                    push( @url_list, $href );
                    $self->{_url_list} = @url_list;
                }

                my $DNS = "dbi:mysql:$DBname:$DBhost:3306";
                $dbh = DBI->connect($DNS, $DBuser, $DBpass ) or die $DBI::errstr;

                $result = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `". $host ."` (URL) VALUES ('$href')");
                if( ! $result->execute() ){
                    $result = $dbh->prepare("CREATE TABLE `". $host ."` ( `ID` INT( 255 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `URL` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY ( `ID` )) ENGINE = MYISAM ;");
                    $result->execute();
                    print "Host added: " . $host . "\n";
                }


                my $content = $response->content;
                die "get failed: " . $href if (!defined $content);
                my @pageLinksArray = ( $content =~ m/href=["']([^"']*)["']/g );
                foreach( @pageLinksArray ) {
                    my $link = $self->trim($_);
                    if( $self->{_max_link} != 0 && scalar @m_href_array > $self->{_max_link} ) {
                        last;
                    }
                    my $new_href = $self->resolve_href( $href, $link );
                    if( $new_href =~ m/^http:\/\// ) {
                        if( substr( $new_href, -1 ) ne "#" ) {
                            my $base = $self->{_url};
                            my %values_index;
                            @values_index{@m_href_array} = ();
                            if( ! $new_href =~ m/$base/ ) {
                                if( $self->{_local} eq "true" && ! exists $values_index{$new_href} ) {
                                    push( @m_href_array, $new_href );
                                    push( @href_array, $new_href );
                                }
                            }elsif( $self->{_local} eq "true" && ! exists $values_index{$new_href} ) {
                                push( @m_href_array, $new_href );
                                push( @href_array, $new_href );
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }            
            }else{
                push( @m_error_array, $href );
            }
        }
    }
}
1;
```

new_spider.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use ACTC;

my ($object, $url, $uri);
print "Starting Poing: (url): ";
chomp($url = <>);

$object = new Crawler( $url );
$object->process_image('process_image_name');
$object->local('true');
$object->max_link(0);
$object->x_more(9999999);
$object->scrape( 'localhost', 'root', '', 'crawl' );

#print $object->{_url} . "\n";
#print $object->{_process_image};
```

Now it's not complete some of the functions are not working correctly but after running the script I have indexed 1500 pages in about an hour which I think is quite slow.

The script started of whipping through the results but now is quite slugish spitting out one url every second.

Can any one give any tips on how to increase performance?

Comment: Looks like an open "optimization" question, maybe a Community Wiki?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Is your CPU at 100%? Or your network connection?

Comment: just checked and yes it is 100%.

Comment: when a href is being crawled it finds any (inbound or outbound) links and then adds then to the array to be processed. Would it be more efficient to store the outbound links in a DB instead of the the array and then when the local site has been scaraped pull another url out of the db and start again? Or maybe when another outbound url has been found, open another cmd window and process that straight away? just thinking outloud.

Comment: Retrieve pages simultaneously, this should increase throughput significantly. And check memory consumption, url queue can grow exlposively.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visit Half Million Pages with Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682759/visit-half-million-pages-with-perl)

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time, your program is probably waiting for a response from the network. There's no away around most of that waiting time (other than putting your computer right next to the computer you want to talk to). Fork off a process to fetch each URL so you can download them simultaneously. You might consider things such as [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Parallel-ForkManager), [POE](http://search.cpan.org/dist/POE), or [AnyEvent](http://search.cpan.org/dist/AnyEvent).

Answer (score 1):

See Brian's answer.

Run lots of copies of it. Use a shared storage system for keeping intermediate and final data.

It might be helpful to take more memory-intensive parts of the crawler (HTML parsing etc) and put those in a separate set of processes.

So have a pool of fetchers which read from the queue of pages to read, and put them into the shared storage area, and a pool of parser processes which read pages and write the results into the results database and queue new pages into the queue to read.

Or something. It really depends on the purpose of your crawler.

Ultimately if you're trying to crawl a lot of pages you'll probably need a lot of hardware and a very fat pipe (to your datacentre/ colo). So you'll need an architecture which allows the parts of the crawler to be split across many machines to scale properly.